# Unable to serve nativephp application

Tags: php, laravel, native-php

I'm using Laravel 10.16.1 and MacOS. I have been trying to serve my  nativePHP application for the first time using `php artisan native:serve` but I get this error:

```
Starting NativePHP dev server…
Fetching latest dependencies…
Starting NativePHP app…

   ErrorException 

  file_get_contents(/home/user/processApp-native/vendor/nativephp/electron/src/Commands/../../resources/js/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Info.plist): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/nativephp/electron/src/Commands/DevelopCommand.php:65
     61▕      * @return void
     62▕      */
     63▕     protected function patchPlist()
     64▕     {
  ➜  65▕         $pList = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../resources/js/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Info.plist');
     66▕ 
     67▕         // Change the CFBundleName to the correct app name
     68▕         $pattern = '/(<key>CFBundleName<\/key>\s+<string>)(.*?)(<\/string>)/m';
     69▕         $pList = preg_replace($pattern, '$1'.config('app.name').'$3', $pList);

      +14 vendor frames 

  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))'
```

Comment: Can you please format the question? It is hard to read as is. Thanks. Also adding directory structure would likely help the question.

Comment: Did you run [`native:install`](https://nativephp.com/docs/1/getting-started/installation#run-the-installer) first?

Comment: I ran 'php artisan native:install' and it installed npm packages successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I need to use sudo before  the command to run successfully

```
$ sudo php artisan native:serve
```

Comment: Do you know why `artisan` requires a super user access? With this command, `artisan` may alter your system.